# AnyLogic, how to change the batch size dynamically?

Tags: anylogic

I have a model where the agents are created by the event but in random manner (uniform_discr(2, 4)). Each group of agents have it's unique number (batchNumber). The size of agents may be different. Then, the model creates the batches of the agents depends on the quantity of the created agents (batchSize). So in this case it may be 2,3 or 4 agents in the batch. It is the number of agents in the batch. Each batch obtains it's volume depends on the volume of it's agents (Resource_quantity).

How to change the batch size and it's volume dynamically?

I used the solution proposed [here](https://noorjax.com/2019/07/02/dynamic-batches/) and used Wait and Batch blocks.

[image: The peace of the model]

[image: Wait block]
[image: Batch block]

The problem is that under the running the model I receive the error (batch capacity must be greater than 0).

I understand that it must be greater than zero and I defined it in the wait block.

What's the problem here?

[image: error]

Comment: shouldn't it be `agent.batchSize` in the "Batch" block field for batch size? (Where you labelled it as "global")?

Comment: AnyLogic doesn't see the agent in these field :( (agent cannot be resolved to a variable )

Comment: which field is it? Would be helpful if you repost the screenshots set to English :)

Comment: @Benjamin, sorry ffor Russian language. I have translated fields into English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you can set the initial batch size to any arbitrary number since no agents will be batched until they are released from the wait block and you set the batch size of the batch block before releasing any agents.

Set the initial batch inside the batch size to any number greater than 0 and see if it works

Comment: It seems that this solve the problem, however I received another error: "class priority.New_modality cannot be cast to class priority.Modality (priority.New_modality and priority.Modality are in unnamed module of loader 'app'). The new agent should be the same as the all similar agents in the model except it's size (the size is the sum of agents in the batch).
"

Comment: Glad my suggestion helps. Can you accept this answer and asks a new question with your new error and add details and screenshots as before.